# Joining Trees in huffman coding

Tags: compression, huffman-code

we have animationhttp://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Huffman_huff_demo.gif
well i cant understand it. 
In huffman algorith we have to join two trees with lowest posiblitiy in first step of animation we join trees with posibility 1 which give us tree with posibility 2.
 So why in next step we join 
    ' 2
with
    m 2
insted of join our 
    b 2 p
tree with
    ' 2
tree ?

Comment: How would you "enumerate" the codez?

Comment: in loop with sorted list of bst's 1st element is just 1 last is n zeros all bewtween are like (position is sorted list) - 1 zeros and 1 at the end

Comment: Huffman codes are not that regular. The bit patterns do not follow that simple scheme because once you join two nodes the combined node might change position in a sorted list arbitrarily.

Comment: so for example if we have such symbols {A,B,C,D} and propability A = 0,1 B = 0,2 C = 0,3 D = 0,4 codes will be A = 100 B = 101 C = 11 D = 0 ?